# C# How to get same coordinate for different image size

Tags: c#, image, coordinates

So i pinpoint a coordinate in an image(1505*1948) with top:310 and left:221. So my question is how i'm gonna get the same location in a smaller image(816*1056)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ratio=1505/816 = 1.8443. the coordinates for the smaller image will be (x/ratio, y/ratio) 
 (310/1.8443, 221/1.8443) => (168.0854, 119.8286).